# Display items of two drop down based on each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have two drop downs with exactly the same values.
I want the drop down 2 to display the values based on the selection of items of drop down 1.
So the selected index of drop down 2 will be equal to or more than the selected index of drop down 1.

```
 document.getElementById("SELECTB").selectedIndex >= document.getElementById("SELECTA").selectedIndex
```

So if B is selected in Drop down 1 then selectable options in drop down 2 will be B,C and D. (A will be not selectable item)

http://jsfiddle.net/xxyhm78t/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution working with pure Javascript:

```
var select1 = document.getElementById("SELECTA");
var select2 = document.getElementById("SELECTB");
select1.onchange = function () {

 while (select2.firstChild) {
    select2.removeChild(select2.firstChild);
 }

 for (var i = select1.selectedIndex; i < select1.options.length; i++) {
    var o = document.createElement("option");
    o.value = select1.options[i].value;
    o.text = select1.options[i].text;
    select2.appendChild(o);
 }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/xuhcr8bf/)

Reference: This is an adjusted solution from [javascript Change the Dropdown values based on other dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990552/javascript-change-the-dropdown-values-based-on-other-dropdown)

**Update:** Like asked in the comment - to disable the options instead of removing them:

```
var select1 = document.getElementById("SELECTA");
var select2 = document.getElementById("SELECTB");
 select1.onchange = function () {

 while (select2.firstChild) {
    select2.removeChild(select2.firstChild);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < select1.options.length; i++) {
    var o = document.createElement("option");
    o.value = select1.options[i].value;
    o.text = select1.options[i].text;
    (i <= select1.selectedIndex) 
  ? o.disabled = true 
  : o.disabled = false ;        
    select2.appendChild(o);
  }
}
```

Adjusted [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/wtLm4805/)

**Update 2:** Like asked in the comment if it's possible to adjust this to use class names instead of ids - yes, by using `getElementsByClassName()`. I've adjusted in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/zeszkoq8/) both `select`s to have `class="SELECTA"` and `class="SELECTB"` instead of the previously used `id`. The according adjustment for the Javascript is only the declaration of the variables:

```
var select1 = document.getElementsByClassName("SELECTA")[0];
var select2 = document.getElementsByClassName("SELECTB")[0];
```

As you already know, an `id` is a unique attribute, therefore it's possible to get a single element using `getElementById()`. `getElementsByClassName()` returns a **collection** of HTML elements instead, even if there's only a single element having the class. So it's - in this example - necessary to address the 1st element of this collection. As counting starts by 0, the first (and only) element having the class "SELECTA" is `getElementsByClassName("SELECTA")[0]`.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName#Syntax

Comment: how can I disable it instead of removing it.  $(select2).attr("disabled", selIndex > k); in js ??

Comment: @PSDebugger I've just updated my answer for the question how to disable the options.

Comment: One small question, Can I use className instead of the ID;s as I have different dropdowns and I cant use the same function (no 2 elements can have the same id)

Comment: @PSDebugger Yes, you can use class names instead of ids - I've just updated my answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using selectedIndex with the following piece of code:

```
$("#SELECTA").change(function() {
    var selIndex = this.selectedIndex;
    $("#SELECTB").find("option").each(function(k,v) {
        $(this).attr("disabled", selIndex > k);
    });
});
```

Depending on what it is you are after, you may need to reset #SELECTB if one of the disabled values is selected.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```js
$("select").on("change", function (e) {
    var sel = this.selectedIndex;
    $("#SELECTB option").each(function (i, e) {
        $(this).prop("disabled", sel > i);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="SELECTA">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
<select id="SELECTB">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
```

And this can be even more general:

```js
$("select").on("change", function (e) {
    var sel = this.selectedIndex;
    var nextSelect = $(this).parent().find("select").not(this);
    $(nextSelect).children().each(function (i, e) {
        $(this).prop("disabled", sel > i);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="SELECTA">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
<select id="SELECTB">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I am using javascript and used your code
but i m not sure how to disable it in js.
$(nextSelect).children().each(function (i, e) {
        $(this).prop("disabled", sel > i);
    }); in js ??