# populating the values in second select box according to previous select box using database in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have database name **compare** and in  that, I have tables **compare1** and **model1**
in the **compare1** table,  I have the brand of mobiles like Samsung and Micromax and in **model1** 
i have models of Samsung brand and Micromax brand such as Samsung Galaxy and Micromax x560 etc.

Now i have a 2 select box which has values which fetch from the database and display in it. in a first select box all brand is fetched and in the second select box, all models is fetched.

now the problem is i want to select the only models in the second select box on the base of brand chosen in the first select box.

for example, if i choose a brand(Samsung) in first select box then in a second select box there should be only Samsung galaxy, Samsung note, Samsung champ etc..

**Note all the values is fetched from databases only**

I don't know how it's possible i m a newbie any help is appreciated.
thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for this, both will require jQuery.

1. You can use an AJAX call to refetch the second list each time the first option is changed, OR
2. You can load all brands of your phones into the second box, with a data attribute like brand="Samsung" and then use jQuery to hide the ones from the brand that's not picked.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes its help but i need a code example to better understanding

Comment: Just like @CriketX explained, you need to add code to run on the client side after you send the page. You can use Javascript or jQuery for this. Try this post for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990552/javascript-change-the-dropdown-values-based-on-other-dropdown