# Hiding an option if its selected in the other select box JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide the option in the selection box if the option is already selected in another box. I am not sure where the problem is in my code, I tried running it on different editors it didn't work. Here is my code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Currency Converter</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script langauge="javascript">
      function CheckDropDowns() {
        ListOfSelectedCountires = [];
        for (CountryNumber = 0; CountryNumber < 3; CountryNumber++) {
          ListOfSelectedCountires[CountryNumber] = document.getElementById("country" + (CountryNumber + 1)).value;
        }
        for (algoritmCountryNumber = 0; algoritmCountryNumber < 3; algoritmCountryNumber++) {
          for (countryOptions = 1; countryOptions < 5; countryOptions++) {
            document.getElementById("country" + (algoritmCountryNumber + 1)).options[countryOptions].style.display = "block";
            for (processedOption = 0; processedOption < 3; processedOption++) {
              if (document.getElementById("country" + (algoritmCountryNumber + 1).options[countryOptions].value == ListOfSelectedCountires[processedOption]) {
                  document.getElementById("country" + (algoritmCountryNumber + 1)).options[countryOptions].style.display = "none";
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
    </script>
    <section>
      <select id="country1" onchange="CheckDropDowns()">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option value="1">Australia</option>
        <option value="2">Indonesian Rupiah</option>
        <option value="3">Chinese Yaun</option>
        <option value="4">Japanese Yen</option>
      </select>
      Convert to
      <select id="country2" onchange="CheckDropDowns()">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option value="1">Australia</option>
        <option value="2">Indonesian Rupiah</option>
        <option value="3">Chinese Yaun</option>
        <option value="4">Japanese Yen</option>
      </select>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The language attribute for script elements was removed aeons ago. Not declaring variables is a recipe for mysterious bugs.

Comment: Very much similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990552/javascript-change-the-dropdown-values-based-on-other-dropdown

Comment: Do you need a vanilla javascript solution, or can you use jQuery?

Comment: @ArleighHix I want the solution in javascript

Comment: @Dev28004 I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

First determine which select needs to be filtered, then loop through the options setting display to block first(to undo the previous filter), and then if the option's value matches the selected value set it's display to none.

**Edit**
Above method does not work in every browser. The better HTML5 way is to set and remove the hidden attribute. I've updated the snippet.

```js
window.CheckDropDowns = function(thisSelect) {
  var otherSelectId = ("country1" == thisSelect.id) ? "country2" : "country1";
  var otherSelect = document.getElementById(otherSelectId);

  for (i = 0; i < otherSelect.options.length; i++) {
    //otherSelect.options[i].style.display = 'block';
    otherSelect.options[i].removeAttribute('hidden');
    if (otherSelect.options[i].value == thisSelect.value) {
      //otherSelect.options[i].style.display = 'none';
      otherSelect.options[i].setAttribute('hidden', 'hidden');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<section>

  <select id="country1" onchange="CheckDropDowns(this)">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="1">Australia</option>
    <option value="2">Indonesian Rupiah</option>
    <option value="3">Chinese Yaun</option>
    <option value="4">Japanese Yen</option>
  </select>
  Convert to
  <select id="country2" onchange="CheckDropDowns(this)">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="1">Australia</option>
    <option value="2">Indonesian Rupiah</option>
    <option value="3">Chinese Yaun</option>
    <option value="4">Japanese Yen</option>
  </select>

</section>
```

Comment: This does nothing in browsers where "none" doesn't hide options. In general, rather than `style.display = 'block'` to un–hide elements you should use `style.display = ''` so that the option adopts its default display value, which is likely not block (e.g. the default for options is inline-block) and may be set to something else by CSS.

Comment: Thanks @RobG for pointing that out. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Great, but I think this is an incorrect use of the hidden attribute (and it doesn't work in Safari). Firstly, it's boolean so `setAttribute('hidden', true)`. Setting it to the string "hidden" works because the string evaluates to true, so the string "false" would set it to `true` too. Secondly, *hidden* shouldn't be used to toggle elements as shown/not shown or that would be shown in some other presentation or context. E.g. hidden form controls are generally never visible. But I guess that's just semantics. :-)

Comment: It's actually just the presence of the attribute, the value is not evaluated as Boolean or otherwise, and `setAttribute('hidden', false)`, `setAttribute('hidden', null)`, and `setAttribute('hidden', '') will all hide the element

Comment: True, but the second argument is required (`setAttribute('hidden')` throws an error) so should be a semantically correct value—IMHO of course. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's wrong with your code, the logic seems convoluted. You can't reliably hide options by setting their *display* to 'none', in some browsers they remain visible. If it was that simple, life would be easy.

You can hide options by removing them from the list, but then you have to remember where they came from so you can put them back when the selection changes.

In the following, each time an option is selected, if there's one stored it's put back and the one matching the selected option is removed. If the first option is selected, the stored one is just put back, nothing is removed.

This only depends on the two selects having the same class value, they could be related by some other value (e.g. a data-* property).

Hopefully the comments are sufficient.

```js
var matchSelected = (function() {
  // Store for "hidden" node
  var nodeStore = {
    sourceElement: null,
    node: document.createDocumentFragment(),
    index: null
  };

  return function(evt) {
    // Get the element that got the event
    var tgt = this;
    // If there's a stored option, put it back
    if (nodeStore.sourceElement) {
      let sel = nodeStore.sourceElement;
      sel.insertBefore(nodeStore.node.firstChild, sel.options[nodeStore.index]);
      nodeStore.sourceElement = null;
      nodeStore.node = document.createDocumentFragment();
      nodeStore.index = null;
    }
    // If the selected option is the first one, stop here
    if (tgt.selectedIndex == 0) return;
    // Get all selects with the same className
    var sels = document.querySelectorAll('.' + this.className);
    // Get the "other" option
    var other = sels[0] == this ? sels[1] : sels[0];
    // Remove and keep the option on the other element that is the same
    // as the selected option on the target element
    nodeStore.sourceElement = other;
    nodeStore.index = tgt.selectedIndex;
    nodeStore.node.appendChild(other.options[tgt.selectedIndex]);
  }
}());

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.countrySelect').forEach(
    node => node.addEventListener('change', matchSelected, false)
   );
}, false);
```

```html
<select id="country1" class="countrySelect">
  <option value="" selected>Choose</option>
  <option value="1">Australia Dollar</option>
  <option value="2">Indonesian Rupiah</option>
  <option value="3">Chinese Yaun</option>
  <option value="4">Japanese Yen</option>
</select>
Convert to
<select id="country2" class="countrySelect">
  <option value="" selected>Choose</option>
  <option value="1">Australia Dollar</option>
  <option value="2">Indonesian Rupiah</option>
  <option value="3">Chinese Yaun</option>
  <option value="4">Japanese Yen</option>
</select>
```