# Set select option value which is depend on another dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two select dropdown as below. Here I want that when I set age 2 from first dropdown then on second dropwdown it should be start from age 3. How can I do it?

```
<select onclick="getAgevalue('age1','age2')" class="select1" id="age1" <?php if($var=='1') {} else { echo ' disabled="disabled"';}?>>
<option><1</option>  
<option>1</option>  
<option>2</option>   
<option>.</option>  
<option>.</option> 
<option>20</option> 
</select>

<select class="select2" id="age2" <?php if($var=='1') {} else { echo ' disabled="disabled"';}?>>
<option><1</option>  
<option>1</option>  
<option>2</option>   
<option>.</option>  
<option>.</option> 
<option>20</option> 
</select>
```

Please reply soon.

also can i use with any function because i have to use it with multiple person's age???

Comment: checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990552/javascript-change-the-dropdown-values-based-on-other-dropdown

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript Change the Dropdown values based on other dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990552/javascript-change-the-dropdown-values-based-on-other-dropdown)

Comment: yes it's working but when i select  set <1 then second dropdown should be start from 1 AND when by default set <1 then second dropdown shoulb start from 1 AND when i select last valune it should be same on second. How to do it?

Comment: and `<?php if($var=='1') {} else { echo ' disabled="disabled"';}?>` conditiont not working with above answer.

Comment: i have 1 to 18 values but it is not working with all

Comment: @albert it is not working properly after around 10 values. I have more then 20 values. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can do by setting onchange event to first dropdown and then compare first dropdown value with second dropdown all values . If greater than show on web page , or not hide it . Also to reset when value change , add default option value .

```js
var select1 = document.getElementById('age1')
var select2 = document.getElementById('age2')

select1.onchange = function() {
  select2.value = null // reset second dropdown value
  for(var i = 0; i < select2.children.length; i++) {
    if(parseInt(select1.value) >= parseInt(select2.children[i].textContent)) {
      select2.children[i].classList.add('disabled')
    } else {
      select2.children[i].classList.remove('disabled')
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.disabled {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<select class="select1" id="age1">
<option value="0"></option>
<option>1</option>  
<option>2</option>   
<option>3</option>  
<option>4</option> 
<option>20</option> 
</select>
<select class="select2" id="age2">
<option></option>
<option>1</option>  
<option>2</option>   
<option>3</option>  
<option>4</option> 
<option>20</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: please tell me how to write loop for 15 min difference using same functionality.