# Jquery .html() not appending informatinon

Tags: jquery, html

I am using Jquery to update some list objects based on a couple of other dropdowns. I got everything working and if I print out the "item" it has the HTML  I need but when I do .html(item) it does not update the HTML.

```
<div class="select-default">
  <select name="vech" id="vechID" class="select-location" asp-for="vech" > 
    <option>Choose Vehicle</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$.getJSON(url2, { scaleId: scaleId, manfId: manfId }, function (data) {  
  var item = " ";
  $("#vechID").empty();
  $.each(data, function (i, vehicle) {
    var results = vehicle.results;
    item += '<option value="' + i + '">' + vehicle + '</option>';
  });
  $("#vechID").html(item);
});
```

Also tried:

```
            var item = "";
            var tmp = document.getElementById("vehcileId").innerHTML;
            alert(tmp);
            $.each(data, function (i, vehicle) {
                item += '<option value="' + i + '">' + vehicle + '</option>';
            });
            document.getElementById("vehcileId").innerHTML += item.toString();
            var tmp = document.getElementById("vehcileId").innerHTML;
            alert(tmp);
            $("#vehcileId").html(item);
```

Update after more testing it was the class. Here is the only code placed on the class though (notice the select-location):

```
  var selectLocation = $('.select-location');
  if (selectLocation.length !== 0){
    selectLocation.selectric({
      arrowButtonMarkup: '<div class="arrow-button"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>',
    });
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried `$("#vechID").append(item);`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript Change the Dropdown values based on other dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990552/javascript-change-the-dropdown-values-based-on-other-dropdown)

Comment: @j08691 It does not I tried that before asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="select-default">
  <select name="vech" id="vechID" class="select-location" asp-for="vech" > 
    <option>Choose Vehicle</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script>
var item = " ";
  var data = ["1","2","3"]
  $("#vechID").empty();
  $.each(data, function (i, vehicle) {
    var results = vehicle.results;
    item += '<option value="' + i + '">' + vehicle + '</option>';
  });
  $("#vechID").html(item);
</script>
```

This code seems to be working.. did you check *data*? Maybe `console.log(data)` to see if it has list of values.

Comment: I printed "item" and it has the html that should be added inside of the select.

Comment: Update... I tried using javascript to change the html and get the elements innerhtml. And it is updated according to javascript but the dropdown does not have the new options. Added in what I also tried.

Comment: mmm.. maybe a JQuery issue then.. I used JQuery CDN in header as below: `<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>` Tested it on chrome

Comment: I'm wondering if it has something to do with and asp.net project? because even javascript isn't working see above.